# RegEx in JavaScript - Start with and Ends with

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract a string using RegEx in Javascript 
for example

```
StudentName nameX = John;
```

or

```
StudentName nameX;
```

I want to extract only "nameX" this is what i've tried so far.

```
var name = allName.match("StudentName(.*);|StudentName(.*)=");
```

what I'm getting is : "nameX = John" , but I'm not getting "nameX" only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex pattern inside of `match`

```
match(/StudentName\s+(\w+)/)[1]
```

See **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7ZzA/)**.​​

Comment: Thanks, that works.
is there a way to find all the objects? for example, if you have StudentName nameX; StudentName nameY; StudentName nameZ; 
can you find all of nameX,y and z ? Thanks

Comment: @kkDev - To find all occurrences use `re = new RegExp()` and `while` loop with `match = re.exec()` condition. Google for it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this non greedy pattern

```
var name = allName.match("StudentName\\s*(.*?)\\s*[=;]");
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gg9EJ/)

Answer (score 1):

If you split on blank spaces then the second match at index 1 should contain the name.

```
var name = allName.split(/[ ;]/g)[1];
```